# How to handle MongoDB exceptions in PySpark?

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using PySpark to do some large scale processing and save some results to a MongoDB instance. I am using the `mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.0.0.jar` to write the dataframe into the MongoDB.

```
df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://username:pwd@mongoinstance:10203/mydb.mycollection").mode("overwrite").save()
```

Sometimes I get exceptions such as `ConnectionException`, `MongoCommandException`,etc. So I want to handle those exceptions. So I added these exception handling snippet but I get `ImportError: No module named com.mongodb`.

```
try:
    df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://username:pwd@mongoinstance:10203/mydb.mycollection").mode("overwrite").save()
except MongoCommandException:
    err_code = MongoCommandException.getErrorCode()
    if err_code == int(16):
        print "Request size is too large to write to Mongo"
```

So can anyone of you help me how to handle exceptions in `PySpark` using `mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.0.0.jar`

Comment: How did you import the jar of mongo-spark-connector in your code?

Comment: You can pass the jar using `--packages` or `--jars` options which `spark-submit` take.

Comment: Trying to use PyCharn. And gave config("spark.jars.packages","org.mongo.....) and used the same way as you. But it is giving NoClassDefFoundError on com/mongodb/ConnectionString. Included all mongo java drivers and I can see this class in the jar...but still this error is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the execution stack where PySpark is utilising the Java `jar`, what you're using/seeing is actually the Java library. 
This is why you don't have access to `com.mongodb` library from within PySpark.

What you could do however, catching the exception from [py4j](https://www.py4j.org/py4j_java_protocol.html) library

```py
from py4j.protocol import Py4JJavaError

try:
    df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
            .option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://username:pwd@mongoinstance:10203/mydb.mycollection")
            .mode("overwrite").save()
except Py4JJavaError, ex: 
     print(ex.java_exception.toString())
     # analyse error stack and handle as needed.
```

See all the direct subclass of [MongoDB Java MongoException class](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoException.html) to see available exceptions to handle.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you!